# Link Salesforce Canvas App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component, canvas

We have canvas app in our managed packaged.

Now we want to link canvas app directly from Contact object component. How do we link .

Also can we provide additional parameters to canvas app from this link ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your issue?

Comment: We have canvas app which loads list of items. (Here all oauth is established). From this user is able to click on individual link to open the item details from there.

Now I am looking for direct way to point to item from one of the layout page example Contact layout page. What would be best way to achieved this?

Comment: You can use Visualforce Page as the location and then just the Canvas Javascript API to display the records.